# How to display HTML article in app? WinRT

Tags: c#, html, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm creating client-side WP 8.1(appx) app for one website.

Well, let's say that I got html code of some article(with images, lists etc), only article(without site's header etc).

I want to display that article in my WP 8.1 app with article's formatting and images.

How can I do that?

I tried using WebView but it's not what I need, because text in WebView is really small and needs zooming and so on.

*** for Tamás Deme ***

```
   <RichTextBlock>
        <common:Properties.Html>
            <![CDATA[ <img width="100" height = "100" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/> ]]>
        </common:Properties.Html>
    </RichTextBlock>
```

It displays p, b tags properly, the only problem is images.

*** for Tamás Deme ***

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the page, and then rerender the article's contents in a [RichTextBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblock.aspx).

To do the conversion these two links I found might help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2013/05/13/displaying-html-content-in-a-richtextblock.aspx and https://github.com/MacawNL/WinRT-RichTextBlock.Html2Xaml

Comment: +1, I did that several times.

Minor gotcha — textures on WP are limited to 2048x2048. If your content is big, split it into paragraphs, and use a RichTextBlock for each paragraph. You can use ItemsControl with appropriate item template to display many stacked RichTextBlock-s.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I got 1 problem, it's not displaying images. Look at my code in question's description

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the JavaScript Windows Store App templates (available in VS2013)?
you can find some good tutorials here:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Maybe, but I dont know JavaScript, I use C#.